# Why can't set eth0 to be my target?

Tags: debian, networking

Here is my  /etc/network/interfaces file.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-driver nl80211
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet static
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

When wifi was closed on my home wireless router,eth0 was activated.
But why the ip is not 192.168.1.101?
Another ip was displayed by ifconfig command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give the same network, much less the same IP address to two different network/interfaces.